# Django saves and updates slow down on partitioned table, but queries are much faster

Tags: django, postgresql, database-partitioning, postgresql-10

I have identical tables in Postgres9 and Postgres10, except that the Postgres10 table is partitioned by state. There are about 80 million records in both tables

When I make a query like this, it is about 10 times faster on the partitioned table than on the Postgres9 unpartitioned table. hooray!

```
# This is fast with a partition, and slow without
parcels = Parcel.objects.filter(state='15', boundary__intersects=polygon)
```

However, when I try to make an update through Django, it is about 1000 times *slower* on the partitioned table (it takes like 2 minutes) than on the Postgres9 version:

```
for parcel in parcels:
    do something
    # This is slow with a partition, and fast without
    parcel.save()
```

But when I make an update directly through psql, it is super fast on the partitioned table in Postgres10, and quite slow on the unpartitioned table in Postgres9:

```
# This is fast with a partition, and slow without
UPDATE parcel SET field=42 WHERE state='15' AND parcel_id='someid';
```

Why would my call to `save` in Django be so much slower than updating directly through psql? Is there an equivalent to `QuerySet.explain()` for `save` operations?

Comment: Have you already checked the sql generated by the ORM?

Comment: No, that's a good idea. Didn't know that I could do that. Trying to figure out how to do it for a `save()` call (vs. via a queryset), now

Comment: Ok, I figured out that it's making a query like `UPDATE parcel SET field=42 WHERE "id" = 'someid';`. Since this does not include the partition key in the where clause, it is slow. The Postgres9 table is fast because `id` is a primary key on that table, but primary keys are not allowed on partitioned tables. So now I am trying to figure out how to add a custom where clause to my `save` call

Comment: If you want to force that syntax, you can use `.filter(parcel_id='some_id', state='some state').update(field1=value1)`

Comment: great idea, I will compare the performance of that to the idea that I had to add a primary key to each "child" table

Comment: Update: doing it that way was a lot faster than what I had before, but a lot slower than adding a primary key for every partition

Answer (score 1):

The reason that Postgres10 was slower than Postgres9 was because partitioned tables do not allow a primary key on the parent. So my call to `parcel.save()` was trying to run a query like `UPDATE parcel SET field=42 WHERE "id" = 'someid';`, but querying by id was extremely slow on the partitioned table.

I fixed this by adding a primary key to each of the child tables. E.g. `ALTER TABLE parcel_01 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);`. When I added it for every child, it had a similar effect, and my update time went down by 99.9%. Overall, using a partitioned table with Postgres10 reduced the total runtime of the tool that I am working on by 75% (from 40 minutes to about 10)

I want to thank @2ps for suggesting that I look at the generated SQL, and for suggesting a way to force the query that I wanted, without using a primary key.